# Cannot find theme.css resource of AdminFaces

Tags: primefaces, adminlte, adminfaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 6.0 to develop a business application. Now my UI looks very primitive. I just want to re-design it by using [AdminFaces](https://adminfaces.github.io/site/) templates (1.0.0-RC18).
I don't have any idea about this, can anyone can help me to solve my issue. How I can implement this template in to my project.

When I add the AdminFaces theme to my project by using following code, I get an error.

pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.adminfaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>admin-template</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-RC18</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.adminfaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>admin-theme</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-RC18</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>admin</param-value>
</context-param>
```

the error:

> cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-admin-1.0.0-rc18" library

Comment: Your setup looks ok, It looks like you have a classpath issue. Do you have a sample project which reproduces the issue to share?